# Flash function executed from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

Hi everyone I guess I have been stupid enough but yet I have been trying to figure out this and I am new on js I need help on how to execute the code below from a JavaScript function when the body unloads this is a flash function but I would like it executed from a js function please help.

```
      public function save():Boolean {
         ExternalInterface.call(this.eventHandler, RecorderJSInterface.SAVE_PRESSED,        this.recorder.currentSoundName);
       try {
      _save(this.recorder.currentSoundName, this.recorder.currentSoundFilename);
        ExternalInterface.call(this.eventHandler, RecorderJSInterface.SAVING,    this.recorder.currentSoundName);
      } catch(e:Error) {
         ExternalInterface.call(this.eventHandler, RecorderJSInterface.SAVE_FAILED, this.recorder.currentSoundName, e.message);
         return false;
        }
         return true;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is my code to call a flash function from javascript:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
function thisMovie(movieName) {
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
         return window[movieName];
     } else {
         return document[movieName];
     }
 }
 function setData(value) {
     thisMovie("yourmovie").save();
 } 
</script>
```

And you have to have your movie embedded like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
         id="yourmovie" width="200" height="200"  codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab">
     <param name="movie" value="yourmovie.swf" />
     <param name="quality" value="high" />
     <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
     <embed src="yourmovie.swf" quality="high" 
         width="200" height="200" name="yourmovie" align="middle"
         play="true" loop="false" quality="high" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
         type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
         pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
     </embed>
 </object>
```